# npm install cordova - Stuck at loadRequestedDeps

Tags: node.js, windows, cordova

I'm trying to install Cordova on my Windows 7 PC.

I tried installing NodeJS and executing `npm install -g cordova`, as suggested in Cordova docs, and it takes forever. So I stopped it and added the `-d` argument to see what was going on.

The output is as follows:

```
> npm install -g -d cordova
  npm info it worked if it ends with ok
  npm info using npm@3.10.8
  npm info using node@v6.9.1
  npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 15:01:30
  npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
  npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
  npm info addNameTag [ 'cordova', 'latest' ]
  [████..............] / loadRequestedDeps: info addNameTag [ 'cordova', 'latest'
```

This is the last step, it will stay there forever. I launched it at 8 this morning, at 14 it was still there.

I already saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984928/installing-cordova-using-cmd-npm-install-g-cordova-gives-error), tried to run cmd as Administrator, it behaves the same.

I already saw [this question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34118282/stuck-when-installing-cordova), even by doing this the output is the same, except for `https` being `http` in the two lines starting with "npm http".

I tried opening `https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova`, the URL exists and I get a big json output from that URL.

I'm not behind firewalls/proxies and I have a 100Mb connection, so internet connection speed is not an issue.

The PC is an Intel i7 2600k, with 8GB RAM and a Samsung 750 Evo SSD, so neither CPU speed nor Disk read/write speed should be an issue.

Why is this happening? Is there a way I can fix it?

Comment: Did you try the answer given in this post? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021968/npm-install-does-not-work-when-running-npm-install-cordova

Comment: @DavidR If you mean the part where it talks about changing the node version no, I didn't. Which version should I try? Regarding proxies, I already said I don't have proxies/firewalls

Comment: Which version you currently have?

Comment: @DavidR Node v6.9.1 LTS (downloaded yesterday), trying to install the latest cordova tools